# Can Alamofire call a different response serializer depending on the content-type of the response?

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

Depending on its mood and information we send in the request, our server might send back an empty-bodied 204 response with content type `text/plain` or something else like a 400-series response with an `application/json` body detailing the error. How should we handle this?

We thought something like this:

```
Alamofire.request(request)
    .responseString({ (request, response, string, error) -> Void in
        // Happy dance
    })
    .responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) -> Void in
        // Parse the error out of the json response and inform the user
    })
```

... but it seems all the chained response handlers are executed. Is there a way to say "only call this one for a specific error type" or "only call this one for a specific response code"?

Are we missing something about how Alamofire is meant to work?

Comment: Maybe you want to do some manual validation? https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#validation

Comment: I don't see how that actually helps me? You chain the response serializer onto the end of the appropriate validation and both the serializers still seem to be run. Can you provide a code example?

Comment: I've not used `validate` yet, came across this looking for answers to a different question as I learn about Alamofire. But it sounds like your response handler would be passed an error object upon validation failure. At which point you could effectively do nothing in your closure? Maybe not optimal/ideal though.

Comment: I found the same behavior - all response closures are executed - so I wrote my own serializing logic based on the response's `Content-Type` header: https://github.com/splinesoft/Bequest/blob/master/src/Bequest/Networking/BQSTHTTPClient.swift#L74

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I recently stumbled upon this myself. Was thinking to rewrite all of my server response to use JSON. (ours also have some sent as `text/plain` and some as `application/json`)

Comment: In 2018 I think the solution is to use NSURLSession directly and avoid Alamofire altogether.